# Evidence Based Scheduling Tool

Tags: fogbugz

Are there any free tools that implement evidence-based scheduling like [Joel talks about](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/10/26.html)? There is FogBugz, of course, but I am looking for a simple and free tool that can apply EBS on some tasks that I give estimates (and actual times which are complete) for.

Comment: Also, FogBugz On Demand is free for 2 users.

Comment: There's a trac plugin in the works. http://github.com/ironsmile/evidencetracplugin

Comment: @ZianChoy I released it on [GitHub](https://github.com/Calmarius/phpebs) today.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FogBugz is free for up to 2 users by the way. As far I know this is the only tool that does EBS.

See here http://www.workhappy.net/2008/06/get-fogbugz-for.html

Answer (score 7):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_Based_Scheduling), Fogbugz is the only product currently offering EBS.

Comment: The Wikipedia article has been deleted and redirected to FogBugz: "The separate Evidence Based Scheduling article has been speedy-deleted as an advertisement."

Comment: at the time of this writing there is another EBS wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence-based_Scheduling